# Twitter User Timeline activity doesn't work on Android 4 and greater

Tags: android, listview, twitter, android-listview, compatibility

I have a Activity created to display a user timeline in a ListView in Android gingerbread it is working fine but when i launch it on a android 4 device the list is blank and the logcat output is:

```
E/log_tag(5083): Error in parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

I have posted the code below:

```
package nl.safan.e_app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener;
import eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TwitterParseHandler extends SherlockActivity {
ArrayList<TwitterFeed> arrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<TwitterFeed>();

class TwitterFeed {
    public String text;
    public String created_at;
}

FancyAdapter aa=null;

static ArrayList<String> resultRow;
private PullToRefreshListView listView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try
    {
        setTheme(TabActivity.THEME);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_parse_handler);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        String result = "";

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=safanbv&count=20&exclude_replies=True&lang=en");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "/n");
                }

                webs.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in converting result "+e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                TwitterFeed resultRow = new TwitterFeed();
                  String date = json_data.getString("created_at");
                  final String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy";
                  SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER,Locale.ENGLISH);
                  sf.setLenient(true);
                  Date created_at = sf.parse(date);
                resultRow.text = json_data.getString("text");
                resultRow.created_at = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(created_at);;

                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        aa=new FancyAdapter();

        myListView.setAdapter(aa);

        listView = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String result = "";
                        try
                        {
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=safanbv&count=20&exclude_replies=True");
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

                            try
                            {
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),8);
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                String line = null;
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb.append(line + "/n");
                                }

                                webs.close();
                                result=sb.toString();
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in converting result "+e.toString());
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                            for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                TwitterFeed resultRow = new TwitterFeed();
                                  String date = json_data.getString("created_at");
                                  final String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy";
                                  SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER,Locale.ENGLISH);
                                  sf.setLenient(true);
                                  Date created_at = sf.parse(date);
                                resultRow.text = json_data.getString("text");
                                resultRow.created_at = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(created_at);;

                                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in parsing data "+e.toString());
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        listView.onRefreshComplete();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TwitterFeed> {
    FancyAdapter() {
        super(TwitterParseHandler.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitterlist, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));

        return(convertView);
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name=null;
    public TextView birthday=null;

    ViewHolder(View row) {
        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.TwitterText);
        birthday=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.TwitterDatum);
    }

    void populateFrom(TwitterFeed r) {
        name.setText(r.text);
        birthday.setText(r.created_at);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /*menu.add("refresh")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);*/
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;

    case Menu.FIRST:
        //examineJSONdata();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   }
   }
```

I hope someone can find the problem.
Thanks in advance!